# OOP related question about classes within classes

Tags: java, class, oop

Context:

So basically I've got a class `Map` which contains a name and another class called `Room`. `Room` contains an int for the amount of doors it has, and a class called `Door`. `Door` contains a char for the position of the door, which can be N(orth), E(ast), S(outh), W(est).

Question:

This is how I've setup my `Room` class:

```
public class Room {
    int doors;
    Door door;


    public Room(int doors, Door door) {
        this.doors = doors;
        this.door = door;
    }
}
```

But this way I can only give it 1 door, and I need to be able to assign an amount of doors that's equivalent to the value of the int doors. Any ideas?

Comment: Additional info: This is my first ever question so my apologies if i made any stupid mistakes or if this sounds like a stupid question. Please feel free to point out any mistakes i've made.

Comment: It depends on your purpose and future usage, but basically you need to have a _collection_ of  `Door`s. It could be achieved using arrays, `List`s, etc.

Answer (score 5):

simply you must use a array or list which can contain multiple doors

```
public class Room {
        Door doors[];
    }
```

Or you can create an array-list if you are not sure with the number of doors when you create the room object because arrays are fixed in size.

```
public class Room {
    List<Door> doors = new ArrayList<Door>();
}
```

If you are using arrays you can initialize the door objects like this using the constructor

```
public Room(int num) {
        this.doors = new Door[num];
        Arrays.fill(this.doors,new Door());
    }
```

Comment: It should be better `List<Door> doors = new ArrayList<Door>();`. It is always better [to program to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/5640649)

Comment: I agree on that @lealceldeiro thanks for enhancing my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `List` to store the `Door`s in `Room` class and add multiple constructors to support creating a `Room` with an array of `Door`s or with a `List` of `Door`s. Also additionally you can define a method to add `Door`s to the `Room` after the instantiation.

```
public class Room {

    private final List<Door> doors = new ArrayList<>();

    public Room(Door... doors) {
        this.doors.addAll(Arrays.asList(doors));
    }

    public Room(List<Door> doors) {
        this.doors.addAll(doors);
    }

    public void addDoor(Door door) {
        this.doors.add(door);
    }

    public List<Door> getDoors() {
        return doors;
    }
}
```

> If you are interested in some suggestions on your `Door` class, please
>   read the below.

Since the direction can be either `N`, `E`, `S` or `W`, it's better to use an `enum` rather than a general `char` value to restrict the direction value only to those 4 values.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of doors. You dont need the number of doors as it will equal the length of the array

Comment: This post is really vague and seems more like a comment (there is a posted comment with more info than this answer). You should put examples, code snippet to help the OP understand your point better.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example use an array of `Door`s:

```
public class Room {
    Door[] doors;


    public Room(int n) {
        this.doors = new Door[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            this.doors[i] = new Door();
        }
    }
}
```

This way you don't even need to store the amount of doors, since it's just the `length` of the `doors` array.